# clear div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to javascript development and stuck with a problem: depending on the selected option in a form, I want first to clear the inner of a div and fill it then with another content by using ajax. This is my current code:

```
$(document).on('change','#uebungsart', function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('zusatz-uebung');
    while(div.firstChild) {
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
    }
});
 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('uebungsart').value == "bet") {  
    $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'helper/javascript-loadings/addOMT.php', 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#zusatz-uebung").html(response);   
            }
        });
    }

    if(document.getElementById('uebungsart').value == "omt") {
    $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'helper/javascript-loadings/addBET.php', 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#zusatz-uebung").html(response);
                }
            });
    }      
});
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work... may somebody help me? :-)

best regards
Florian

Comment: doesn't work how exactly? What error / unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Do you understand how to debug your code in detail? You'll need to be more specific about the problem before we can give you much help.

Comment: What I can see though is that you're running the AJAX immediately when your page loads (if either of the conditions is met), but not when the selection changes in your form

Comment: As an aside, your code is an odd mix of jQuery and standard JavaScript syntax. It's generally better to choose one style and stick to it, it makes your code a lot more readable. If you're going to use jQuery for DOM manipulation, then it makes sense to use jQuery wherever you can. If you're not going to use jQuery, then avoid it entirely.

Comment: These two snippets should be combined. You'll want your if statements inside the change event, otherwise when you change the select, the ajax won't be fired.

Comment: with my posted code, it didn't cleared the response div, so there was everytime the same content displayed. But with your hints, I edited my code so everything works fine now. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your hints, I edited my code to the following:

```
$(document).on('change','#uebungsart', function() {
           document.getElementById('zusatz-uebung').innerHTML = "";
            if(document.getElementById('uebungsart').value == "bet") {
                $.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: 'helper/javascript-loadings/addOMT.php', 
                    success: function(response) {            
                        $("#zusatz-uebung").html(response);
                        }
                });
            }

            if(document.getElementById('uebungsart').value == "omt") {
                $.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: 'helper/javascript-loadings/addBET.php', 
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#zusatz-uebung").html(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
```

Now it clears the content of the response-div correctly and loads the response of both php-Scripts depending on the selected option

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<form action="">
 <label for="fname">DATA:</label>
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="datawithquery(this.value)">
</form>
<p>User: <span id="show"></span></p>

function datawithquery(id) {
  if (id.length == 0) {
  document.getElementById("fname").placeholder = "none data";
return;
}
else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "helper/javascript-loadings/addBET.php?q="+id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}
}